# FQL subquery breaks top query and never returns

Tags: facebook-fql

We have a FQL query that used to work and stopped somewhere around Oct 16.  No help from Facebook on this.

This code used to work:

```
    SELECT object_id, metric, end_time, period, value 
      FROM insights 
     WHERE object_id IN
         (
      SELECT page_id 
      FROM page_admin 
      WHERE uid=123
      AND page_id<>456
      AND page_id<>789
  ) 
AND metric="page_audio_plays"
AND end_time=end_time_date("2011-11-11" ) 
AND period=86400
```

If I run the inner Select, it returns a large list of page_id's.  IF I remove the inner select and replace with a list of comma seperated id's like this:

```
...where object_id in ( 123, 456, 8778, 999)
```

The overall query runs.

With the original code above, the query never returns and times out.

Question:  Is anyone aware of something on FB side that broke around the middle of October in this regards?  Or is there something inherently wrong with doing a subquery like this?

Any suggestions on how to work around?

Answer (score 0):

Net:  query returned TOO much data.  If you have this problem, break up the result set somehow so it returns a smaller set of data.  Would be nice if API returned some discernable status telling you so but....